# Frist-Aid Fatal mysql server error after data migration stopped

Tags: mysql, centos, migration

Mysql after stop,'service mysqld stop' My orders are as follows ,And then you can't connect it, you can't start it, and the error is

> Failed to start mysql.service: Access denied
>   See system logs and 'systemctl status mysql.service' for details.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this with root privileges. Сheck permissions for folders and files, show logs and 'systemctl status mysql.service'

Comment: 'systemctl status mysql.service' after ,
Unit mysql.service could not be found.